# .so file not found (unsatisfiedlinkerror), but it exist

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've been struggling with this for a while, and although I have found many having similar problems, their fixes don't seem to work for me. Perhaps I am misunderstanding something though, regarding of where the shared library files go after installing an APK.

Setup: Android, using a build.gradle file, and CMakeLists.txt since I want to run some C++ code using JNI. I followed the tutorial basically from https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code, along with other pieces here and there from other websites.

My C++ code works correctly (it only returns a number). The APK generated can be unzipped, and I see all the .so files under the lib directory. Inside /lib there are four directories, each one for a different arquitecture, including my target (ARM). However, when I install the APK and try to run my C++ code portion, it returns an unsatisfiedlinkerror with the message saying "We looked for your .so file on nativeDirs under /system/lib and /vendor/lib, but we didn't find it)."

Now, if I instead push the .so file from the unzipped APK, into the location they mention, everything will run correctly (so at least my code is compiled correctly). Am I misunderstanding something? I was also reading that it appears that the .so files are not extracted from the APK anymore, but still, it's not finding it. I actually can't find the .so file in the system at all, but again, if I extract the APK it will be there.

My CMakeLists.txt simply have the parameters based on: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/configure-cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(native SHARED
        nativeCode.cpp)

target_link_libraries(native
        android
        log)
```

I'm loading my library as:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native");
}
```

My questions are:

1. First of all, where should the .so files exist in my device after installing the APK.
2. Should I specify in any way the location of where the .so files should be under CMakeLists.txt?
3. If I need to specify a path for the app to look for the .so files, where should this be?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 3. An environment variable called `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Thanks Elliott, could you explain to me what is the purpose of adding that path? Wouldn’t this be to tell the app where to look for the .so files? If so, my problem is that the .so file does not seem to be copied into the system. Again, I might be misunderstanding something. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i'm answering your question one by one...

1. QUESTION : First of all, where should the .so files exist in my device after installing the APK ?

- Starting From **Android M**, it supports **uncompressed native librarie**s in APKs, which allows the platform to read the native libraries **directly from the APK** without having to extract them.It have the flag **android:extractNativeLibs** which is default **false**. This is why you don't see them in the **"data/data/packagename/lib/"** directory if you're testing on a device on Android M or later.
- Ultimately for testing purpose you can use **android:extractNativeLibs="true**" in Application tag of AndroidManifest.xml, to see in "data/data/packagename/lib/" folder.

  ```
       <application
        android:extractNativeLibs="true">
          ...
       </application>
  ```

2. QUESTION: Should I specify in any way the location of where the .so files should be under CMakeLists.txt?

- Considering your **nativecode.cpp** in **rootPath/app/src/main/cpp/nativecode.cpp**, and your CMakeList.txt under **roothPath/app** , your CmakeList.txt **add_library** should be like below,

  ```
    add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
    nativecode
    # Sets the library as a shared library.
    SHARED
    # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
    src/main/cpp/nativecode.cpp)
  ```

> If you notice, i added **relative path** and i don't know about case Sensitive. please try with **smallcase**.

- I noticed, you mentioned your lib name as "**nativeCode**" , but in Code you taken only (System.loadLibrary(**"native"**)), it should be nativeCode. make sure the name matches for your library.
- Add path of your CMakeList.txt in **build.gradle** (App Level)

  android{

  ```
    ...

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt" //consider this CMakeLists.txt inside rootPath/app/CMakeLists.txt
        }
    }
  ```

3. QUESTION : If I need to specify a path for the app to look for the .so files, where should this be?

- If you follow above steps it will work, **You no need to specify** which is modern and easy way., but if you wish manually i'm sure it bit complex compared to above(atleast for me)
- First you have to create .so files from your .cpp file. (for that,we can do with **Android.mk** and **Application.mk**)
- Then, you can add following line in **build.gradl**e app level.

  ```
  android{
     ...
     ...
    sourceSets {
      main {
         jniLibs.srcDir 'jniLibs' //consider this jniLibs folder under rootPath\app\src\main\jniLibs
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Then, you have to add *.so files in **rootPath/app/jniLibs/**/*.so**.
  You have to generate *.so files for all supported ARM like, ("x86", "x86_64", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a")

then your folder path something like ,

1. rootPath\app\src\main\jniLibs\**arm64-v8a**\libnativecode.so,
2. rootPath\app\src\main\jniLibs\**arm64-v7a**\libnativecode.so
   and so on...

Hope, these clear your issues and your doubts aswell .

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the thorough explanation. The names match for me, sorry I was just removing the name of my library while posting here. But they both matches. 

The directory structure is exactly as you mention, and I do use the path to the cpp file as you mentioned. 

I’m not entirely sure of what is the difference with mine. It compiles but it just doesn’t find it. 

cmake path is in build.gradle. Cmakelist under root/app. Adding library as you mentioned, and giving the relative path to the cpp file. I also use target link libraries (should I specify anything else here besides the lib?).

Comment: I am tempted to try your alternative approach but I don’t know if it’s a good practice since it seems that my error is somewhere else.

Comment: Are You added CMakelist path in Build.gradle…?

Comment: If possible share the git repo i will look into it and will update you.

Comment: Try it official google sample. Which is very simple hello world kind of ndk proj. Try run and check is this working or not . Link : https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/hello-jni

Comment: Yes, I did add in build.gradle the path to cmakelist. Build.gradle is under root/app. Along with cmakelist.txt. Added as: externalNativeBuild{ cmake { path “CMakeLists.txt}}. 

I also included a specific version (3.10.2). And inside cmakelist.txt I specified the library just as you described. This is pretty much a hello world, everything compiles just doesn’t find it. Hence why if I move it manually it works. I will take a look at the GitHub you attached. I don’t understand where my error is since I had tried this from scratch a few times. Thanks again!

Comment: Yup! Don’t worry these are common. Be patient it will work. Try it the best and different approach might be a very small mistake. check the code make it happend no matter what..

Comment: Unfortunately I’m at a loss. Is there any special permission that I should use if it’s a system app? I can see in the logs that it is in fact trying to look for the .so file inside: nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/myapp/myapp.apk!/lib/arm]] couldn’t find libnative.so. Along with a few other directories. Again, if I unzip the APK file the directory lib/arm exist, and the .so file is inside. So I was thinking maybe I need to give a special permission to the app?

Comment: Nope, as i told starting from android version M, no need to unzip or extract lib in another folder. It will work without extracting to any another folder like dex,assests files. So thats the reason you only see inside .apk file